# Здраствуйте вообщем мне надо сделать в Laravel Voyager моя таблица my_objects отображается в bread мне надо чтобы она отобразилась

Tags: laravel

Здраствуйте вообщем мне надо сделать в Laravel Voyager моя таблица my_objects отображается в bread мне надо чтобы она отобразилась в левом боковом меню как мне это сделать? В voyager.php добавляю в модели не получается .[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)